# Bind middleware to controller in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to use middleware in my controller , but I don't know route beforehand, as I take slug from my DB.

Is it possible in laravel 5?

Thank you in advance

Comment: yes, it is. what you want to achieve? did you try anything before?

Comment: I use middleware for admin side , where all routes are known and it's working, but on site side, I use slugs and bind controllers accordingly . in this case, middleware is not working. Global middlewares are but I want it on certain controllers. thank you!

Comment: first, create middleware as your requirement, then you call middle using different method like:
`Route::get('admin/profile', ['middleware' => 'auth', function(){}]);` or `$this->middleware('auth');` in your controller __construct.

Answer (score 5):

Inside your controller's constructor, do the following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    //This will apply to every method inside the controller
    $this->middleware('auth');

    //This will apply only to the methods listed inside the array
    $this->middleware('log', ['only' => ['fooAction', 'barAction']]);

    //This will apply only to the methods except the ones listed inside the array
    $this->middleware('subscribed', ['except' => ['fooAction', 'barAction']]);
}
```

You can read about that [here](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#controller-middleware)

Comment: I use middleware like this  for known routes and it's working, but if I dont know the route before,  it doesn't work

Comment: I get that part, but you gotta know at least the structure of your site. You have a slug, so you must have something like /some_route/{slug} or similar. Worst case scenario, just fire one method inside a controller for every route and apply some logic to redirect. Show us the routes.php file to give you more help.

Comment: Route::get('/{lang}/myroute', 'MyController@myMethod'); -
 In this case middleware is working of course. I have it in MyController like $this->middleware('name');    
 " Route::get('{lang}/{slug}/{params?}', 'PagesController@getPage')->where('params', '(.*)');  "   In this case, PagesController decides which controller to load. When it calls MyController  here , middleware is not working, as it's depended  on routes , it,s logical .
Thank you very much for your time :))